# How do i extract one or multiple URLs from a text (NVARCHAR(MAX)) column

Tags: sql-server, regex, t-sql, substring

I have a data column in my table, and in this column there can be zero, one or multiple URLs along other text on each row. I would like to extract these URLs into a new dataset containing only these.

Why? Because I want to add some of these URLs to a block list in my DB to prevent spam.

For example, I have this text in the data column:

```
hmaruqbtufcvdlfu, <a href="httx://portugal-forex.com/">Day forex signal strategy trading</a>, KzxiIIO, [url=httx://portugal-forex.com/]Forex Broker[/url], mtNZQDi, httx://portugal-forex.com/ The best forex broker, IBWlBzg, <a href="httx://phen375treatment.com/">Avantage inconveniant phen 375</a>, ApEuXTp, [url=httx://phen375treatment.com/]Phen375[/url], QDVLpSn, httx://phen375treatment.com/ Where to buy phen 375, Fnwpugj, <a href="httx://priligy2000.org/">Priligy t</a>, zwRZhIC, [url=httx://priligy2000.org/]Order priligy[/url], FBgSaWs, httx://priligy2000.org/ Priligy buy online, FsemWnW, <a href="httx://ossorio.org/">Online Casino</a>, aOBtTaK, [url=httx://ossorio.org/]Online Casino[/url], oMMMacf, httx://ossorio.org/ Free online casino bounuses, occFLyZ, <a href="httx://paroxetine247.com/">Paroxetine adema</a>, xvrIdnq, [url=httx://paroxetine247.com/]Paroxetine depression[/url], MLSRAXX, httx://paroxetine247.com/ Paroxetine dark skin, GLYTcZY, <a href="httx://resolvedisputes.org/">Fioricet prescription online</a>, PmEMaMA, [url=httx://resolvedisputes.org/]Fioricet wcodiene for headache[/url], vPlKLhq, httx://resolvedisputes.org/ Online pharmacy fioricet, fxfhRcV.
```

Then I want all URLs in the text:

```
httx://portugal-forex.com/
httx://phen375treatment.com/
httx://priligy2000.org/
And so on.
```

I really dont know where to start the do this in SQL.

Comment: you need get only main domain like httx://portugal-forex.com/ or can be also httx://portugal-forex.com/xxx?Page=2

Comment: Main domain is enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is example. I search string from "httx://" to first "/" :

In any case you will need go one by one row.

Put code to Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Temporary.getLinksFromText (@Tekstas NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Data TABLE(TheLink NVARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @FirstIndexOfChar INT,
            @LastIndexOfChar INT,
            @LengthOfStringBetweenChars INT ,
            @String VARCHAR(MAX)

   SET @FirstIndexOfChar    = CHARINDEX('httx://',@Tekstas,0) 

    WHILE @FirstIndexOfChar > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @String = ''
        SET @LastIndexOfChar    = CHARINDEX('/',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar+7)
        SET @LengthOfStringBetweenChars = @LastIndexOfChar - @FirstIndexOfChar + 1

        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar,@LengthOfStringBetweenChars)
        INSERT INTO @Data (TheLink) VALUES (@String);

        SET @Tekstas = SUBSTRING(@Tekstas, @LastIndexOfChar, LEN(@Tekstas))
        SET @FirstIndexOfChar = CHARINDEX('httx://',@Tekstas, 0) 

    END 

    RETURN
END
```

Create some testing data:

```
CREATE TABLE  #Data(weLink NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES 
('hmaruqbtufcvdlfu, <a href="httx://portugal-forex.com/">Day forex signal strategy trading</a>, KzxiIIO, [url=httx://portugal-forex.com/]Forex Broker[/url], mtNZQDi, httx://portugal-forex.com/ The best forex broker, IBWlBzg, <a href="httx://phen375treatment.com/">Avantage inconveniant phen 375</a>, ApEuXTp, [url=httx://phen375treatment.com/]Phen375[/url], QDVLpSn, httx://phen375treatment.com/ Where to buy phen 375, Fnwpugj, <a href="httx://priligy2000.org/">Priligy t</a>, zwRZhIC, [url=httx://priligy2000.org/]Order priligy[/url], FBgSaWs, httx://priligy2000.org/ Priligy buy online, FsemWnW, <a href="httx://ossorio.org/">Online Casino</a>, aOBtTaK, [url=httx://ossorio.org/]Online Casino[/url], oMMMacf, httx://ossorio.org/ Free online casino bounuses, occFLyZ, <a href="httx://paroxetine247.com/">Paroxetine adema</a>, xvrIdnq, [url=httx://paroxetine247.com/]Paroxetine depression[/url], MLSRAXX, httx://paroxetine247.com/ Paroxetine dark skin, GLYTcZY, <a href="httx://resolvedisputes.org/">Fioricet prescription online</a>, PmEMaMA, [url=httx://resolvedisputes.org/]Fioricet wcodiene for headache[/url], vPlKLhq, httx://resolvedisputes.org/ Online pharmacy fioricet, fxfhRcV.'),
('hmaruqbtufcvdlfu, <a href="httx://portugal-forex.com/">Day forex signal strategy trading</a>, KzxiIIO, [url=httx://portugal-forex.com/]Forex Broker[/url], mtNZQDi, httx://portugal-forex.com/ The best forex broker, IBWlBzg, <a href="httx://phen375treatment.com/">Avantage inconveniant phen 375</a>, ApEuXTp, [url=httx://phen375treatment.com/]Phen375[/url], QDVLpSn, httx://phen375treatment.com/ Where to buy phen 375, Fnwpugj, <a href="httx://priligy2000.org/">Priligy t</a>, zwRZhIC, [url=httx://priligy2000.org/]Order priligy[/url], FBgSaWs, httx://priligy2000.org/ Priligy buy online, FsemWnW, <a href="httx://ossorio.org/">Online Casino</a>, aOBtTaK, [url=httx://ossorio.org/]Online Casino[/url], oMMMacf, httx://ossorio.org/ Free online casino bounuses, occFLyZ, <a href="httx://paroxetine247.com/">Paroxetine adema</a>, xvrIdnq, [url=httx://paroxetine247.com/]Paroxetine depression[/url], MLSRAXX, httx://paroxetine247.com/ Paroxetine dark skin, GLYTcZY, <a href="httx://resolvedisputes.org/">Fioricet prescription online</a>, PmEMaMA, [url=httx://resolvedisputes.org/]Fioricet wcodiene for headache[/url], vPlKLhq, httx://resolvedisputes.org/ Online pharmacy fioricet, fxfhRcV.')
```

And you can execute it like this (without cursor)

```
SELECT allLinks.*
FROM #Data AS D
OUTER APPLY Temporary.getLinksFromText (D.weLink) AS allLinks
```

Comment: This solution works but then i have to create a cusor to process all rows which is not optimal. Is it possible to do it without a cursor? =) Setbased instead. I would like to process this statement "SELECT Data FROM Paste WHERE paste.CaptchaOK = 0".

Comment: what you mean paste.CaptchaOK = 0?

Comment: I think you will need go one by one in any case. check updated answer.

Comment: "paste.CaptchaOK = 0" Its just my selection, nothing to care about. =)