# Assign value to parameter inside of a function via table parameter query (or how do I find the lowest non-ZERO value from 4 separate parameters?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Okay, so I'm working on this Microsoft SQL database table that contains message strings, and I am trying to identify all of the URLs in those strings via starting with `'www.'` and ending with either (`'.biz','.com','.net','.org'`).

I found a very useful function written by StackOverflow member [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1692632/darka] at [[How do i extract one or multiple URLs from a text (NVARCHAR(MAX)) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656154/how-do-i-extract-one-or-multiple-urls-from-a-text-nvarcharmax-column]).

I modified his function to suit my purpose.... adding parameters to find the LastIndexOfChar for the various domain types.  But I've run into a problem.  I have to assign the @LastIndexOfChar parameter with the lowest non-zero value from 4 seperate parameters.

My original idea was to use some kind of temp table, but apparently I can't use those inside of a function, so I tried a Table Variable.  But even so, I'm unable to select from the Table Variable inside of my function.

So, how do I find the lowest non-zero value from these 4 parameters?  If all 4 are 0, then we'd pass 0 and end the loop.

Below is my function code:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getLinksFromText (@Tekstas NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Data TABLE(TheLink NVARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FirstIndexOfChar INT,
        @LastIndexOfChar INT,
        @LengthOfStringBetweenChars INT,
        @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @LastIndexOfCharBIZ INT,
        @LastIndexOfCharCOM INT,
        @LastIndexOfCharNET INT,
        @LastIndexOfCharORG INT

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ( ParameterName varchar(20), LastIndexOfChar INT);

SET @FirstIndexOfChar    = CHARINDEX('www.',@Tekstas,0) 

WHILE @FirstIndexOfChar > 0
BEGIN

    SET @String = ''
    SET @LastIndexOfCharBIZ =   CHARINDEX('.biz',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar)
    SET @LastIndexOfCharCOM =   CHARINDEX('.com',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar)
    SET @LastIndexOfCharNET =   CHARINDEX('.net',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar)
    SET @LastIndexOfCharORG =   CHARINDEX('.org',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar)
    SET @LastIndexOfChar    = CHARINDEX('.com',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar + 0)  -- this the default type of domain we're looking for.

    INSERT INTO @TempTable
    VALUES ('BIZ', @LastIndexOfCharBIZ), ('COM', @LastIndexOfCharCOM), ('NET', @LastIndexOfCharNET), ('ORG', @LastIndexOfCharORG)

    -- The line below is commented out, because that's where this function breaks...  it doesn't allow me to do a select from the table variable
    --SET @LastIndexOfChar =  COALESCE(SELECT MIN(LastIndexOfChar) FROM @TempTable  WHERE LastIndexOfChar > 0),0)

    SET @LengthOfStringBetweenChars = @LastIndexOfChar - @FirstIndexOfChar + 4

    IF (@LastIndexOfChar = 0)
        BREAK;

    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar,@LengthOfStringBetweenChars)
    INSERT INTO @Data (TheLink) VALUES (@String);

    SET @Tekstas = SUBSTRING(@Tekstas, @LastIndexOfChar, LEN(@Tekstas))
    SET @FirstIndexOfChar = CHARINDEX('www.',@Tekstas, 0) 

END 

RETURN
END
```

Any suggestions or ideas on how to find the smallest non-zero value out of the four parameters @FirstIndexOfCharBIZ, @FirstIndexOfCharCOM, @FirstIndexOfCharNET, @FirstIndexOfCharORG would be very helpful!

Please note, the message strings that I'm extracting from might not contain any domains or it might contain multiple domains.  I want to identify all the domains within the strings.  Below are a few example of the row of strings where I'm trying to extract domains from:

1 `Hello, please fix my website at http://www.example.biz, thanks!`

Our Function would return `www.example.biz`

2 `Client name: Example Company website: www.example.net/test.html  message:  Can we find someone to improve our SEO rankings with www.google.com??`

Our Function would return 2 values: `www.example.net` and `www.google.com`

3 `Dear Support, our website at mywebsite.com isn't loading, can you fix?`

Our Function would not return any values, as the above domain is missing the www portion (this is fine).

Comment: SQL Server isn't good for parsing text. I'd suggest creating your parsing function in C# (for example) with regex and creating a CLR function that SQL Server executes to parse.

Comment: @EzLo Yeah, I think you're right. I just don't have experience doing what you suggested, and I felt like I was really close to a solution with what I had, even if it was imperfect or inefficient.  I appreciate your comment, and I'll look into doing a CLR function in the future.  If you have a suggestion of a good resource for that, let me know, otherwise I'll google around.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Had to make a quick edit to my code/answer, as there was a small bug**  Basically commented out the `IF` statement for `(@LastIndexOfChar >= 500)` and replaced it with `(@LengthOfStringBetweenChar >= 500)`.

---

**Original answer:**
Okay, I kept banging away at this problem for most of today and **finally got the function to work the way I intended**.  Below is the full source code of my function, along with notes to explain what's going on:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.getLinksFromText (@Tekstas NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @Data TABLE(TheLink NVARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @FirstIndexOfChar INT,
        @LastIndexOfChar INT,
        @LengthOfStringBetweenChars INT,
        @String NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @TLDType VARCHAR(20),
        @LastIndexOfCharBIZ INT,
        @LastIndexOfCharCOM INT,
        @LastIndexOfCharNET INT,
        @LastIndexOfCharORG INT

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ( ParameterName varchar(20), LastIndexOfChar INT);

SET @FirstIndexOfChar    = CHARINDEX('www.',@Tekstas,0) 

WHILE @FirstIndexOfChar > 0
BEGIN
    -- @String will be the output, so we must first clean/initalize it. 
    SET @String = ''

    -- @LastIndexOfChar is used to determine how far to look for the TLD portion.
    SET @LastIndexOfCharBIZ =   CHARINDEX('.biz',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar + 0)
    SET @LastIndexOfCharCOM =   CHARINDEX('.com',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar + 0)
    SET @LastIndexOfCharNET =   CHARINDEX('.net',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar + 0)
    SET @LastIndexOfCharORG =   CHARINDEX('.org',@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar + 0)

    -- Populate the temp tables with values of where the TLDs are.  If the TLDs aren't found, their values will be 0.  
    INSERT INTO @TempTable
    VALUES ('BIZ', @LastIndexOfCharBIZ), ('COM', @LastIndexOfCharCOM), ('NET', @LastIndexOfCharNET), ('ORG', @LastIndexOfCharORG)

    -- The line below is how we get the smallest non-zero LastIndexOfChar value.  If there are no values to pass over, then we use 0.
    SET @LastIndexOfChar =  (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(LastIndexOfChar),0) FROM @TempTable  WHERE LastIndexOfChar > 0)

    SET @LengthOfStringBetweenChars = @LastIndexOfChar - @FirstIndexOfChar + 4

    --Break out of loop if limits are reached (Last index = 0 or length of string between chars = 500+)
    IF (@LastIndexOfChar = 0)
        BREAK;
    --IF (@LastIndexOfChar >= 500)
    IF (@LengthOfStringBetweenChars >= 500)
        BREAK;

    SET @String = SUBSTRING(@Tekstas,@FirstIndexOfChar,@LengthOfStringBetweenChars)
    INSERT INTO @Data (TheLink) VALUES (@String);

    SET @Tekstas = SUBSTRING(@Tekstas, @LastIndexOfChar, LEN(@Tekstas))
    SET @FirstIndexOfChar = CHARINDEX('www.',@Tekstas, 0)

    -- We must clean out the temptable before we start the next loop
    DELETE FROM @TempTable

END 

RETURN
END
```

**It turns out that I can run a SELECT**... but I just needed to change how it was written in order for SQL to accept it as valid.  Originally, I was trying to Coalesce outside of the query, rather than inside.  Once I did that, and put my select statements inside of (), things started to work.

Previously, I had
`SET @LastIndexOfChar =  COALESCE(SELECT MIN(LastIndexOfChar) FROM @TempTable  WHERE LastIndexOfChar > 0),0)`
Instead, it should have been written as
`SET @LastIndexOfChar =  (SELECT COALESCE(MIN(LastIndexOfChar),0) FROM @TempTable  WHERE LastIndexOfChar > 0)`

In addition, I had to add another IF statement to break out of the loop if the LengthOfStringBetweenChars was 500+.  And delete the @TempTable contents at the end of the loop so that it was ready for the next loop.  Once those things were figured out, I was able to apply the function to my table and get a full set of results via:

```
SELECT MT.ID, MT.BodyText, allLinks.*
FROM MessageTable AS MT
OUTER APPLY dbo.getLinksFromText (MT.BodyText) AS allLinks
```

**This function uses a lot of resources on the SQL Server**, thus there are probably better solutions out there.  User EzLo made a good point in his comment on my question that this probably should be done in C#, and I agree, but I felt like I was super close to this solution, and didn't want to abandon it and have to start all over with a new language.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question of simply identifying strings that start with `www.` and end with one of your TLDs, why not use:

```
    SELECT string FROM table 
        WHERE RIGHT(string,4) = 'www.'
        AND LEFT(string,4) IN ('.biz','.com','.net','.org')
        ORDER BY string
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, however the "string" that I'm pulling from my table are messages that aren't just single strings, but contain full conversations that may contain several URLs (or none) that can be extracted.  I'll update my question with some example of the dataset.